# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 15, Size: 5

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi I'm trying to do the first problem in project euler which asks the
     sum of multiples of 3 or 5 under 1000. Here is the code I've made.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MultiplesOf3And5 {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int x = 0; // multiples of 3
        int y = 0; // multiples of 5
        int sum = 0; // sum of the multiples of 3 or 5
        int quotient3; //check for the remainder of numbers that are multiples of 3
        int quotient5; //check for the reaminder of numbers that are multiples of 5

        ArrayList<Integer> multiples = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        while ( x <= 999 && y <= 1000)
        {

            quotient3 = x % 3; // check remainder 
            quotient5 = y % 5; // check reaminder

            if (quotient3 == 0 && quotient5 == 0) // check if both x and y are multiples of 3 and 5
            {
                multiples.add(x); // if true put it in a arraylist
            }

            if (quotient3 == 0) // checks if x is a multiples of 3 
            {
                if (multiples.contains(x)) // check if x is already in the arraylist 
                {
                    EmptyStatement:;
                }
                else {
                    multiples.add(x); // add x in the arraylist 
                }
            }

            if (quotient5 == 0)
            {
                if (multiples.contains(y))
                {
                    EmptyStatement:;
                }
                else {
                    multiples.add(y);
                }
            }

            x+=3;
            y+=5;

        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= multiples.size(); i++) // loop into the arraylist and get the sum of the elements
        {
            int value = (int) multiples.get(i);
            sum = sum + value;
        }
        System.out.print(sum);
    }
}
```

After fixing some compiler error I managed to compile it. But once I run it I'm having error that says,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 15, Size: 5
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheckForAdd(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
at MultiplesOf3And5.main<MultiplesOf3And5.java:23)
```

I've searched about this error, but I can't still make it work.

Comment: Can't be a good developer without learning how to take a turn through a debugger and see exactly where your erroneous assumptions conflict with what the code is actually doing.  You've gone past the end of your array, of course.

Comment: Take a closer look at the stacktrace. It will point you to the line in your code where the IndexOutOfBoundsException is triggered. That should help you to further analyze the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seen your loop time is more than your arraylist size.
You must use **i < multiples.size();** instead of **i <= multiples.size();**.

So, replace your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= multiples.size(); i++) 
// loop into the arraylist and get the sum of the elements
        {
        int value = (int) multiples.get(i); 
        sum = sum + value;
        }
```

With:

```
for (int i = 0; i < multiples.size(); i++) 
// loop into the arraylist and get the sum of the elements
        {
        int value = (int) multiples.get(i); 
        sum = sum + value;

        }
```

Comment: It is now working. thanks for the correction. Now I can focus on getting the correct answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The arrayList is zero based so if arraylist.size = 400 then your highest index is 399.
The loop should use `less than (<)`  instead of `less than or equal to (<=)`

Answer (score 0):

What about using

```
for(int i : multiples){

sum += i ;

}
```

Much more simple and this kind of statement would at least not run into any overflows.